# how to store data frame into base with duplicated key?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I have a data frame like this:

```
+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|               time|    key|  sequence|                kind|              binary|
+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1528848000000000000|BTC-USD|6066746240|              EventA|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000000000000|BTC-USD|6066746241|              EventB|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000000000000|BTC-USD|6066746242|              EventC|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000001000000|BTC-USD|6066746243|              EventB|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000001000000|BTC-USD|6066746244|              EventA|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000003000000|BTC-USD|6066746245|              EventA|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000003000000|BTC-USD|6066746246|              EventC|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
|1528848000003000000|BTC-USD|6066746247|              EventA|[0E 42 54 43 2D 5...|
+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

This is a typical time series data, and it is sorted by the time column. But the time column might have duplicated entry (multiple events can happen in the same time)

Now I want to use `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` to save this data into hbase. Here is what I did in scala:

```
rdd.map{row =>
  val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row.time.toString))
  put.addColumn(SequencedMessageRow.messagesColumnFamilyBinary, SequencedMessageRow.keyColumnBinary, Bytes.toBytes(row.key))
  put.addColumn(SequencedMessageRow.messagesColumnFamilyBinary, SequencedMessageRow.sequenceColumnBinary, Bytes.toBytes(row.sequence))
  put.addColumn(SequencedMessageRow.messagesColumnFamilyBinary, SequencedMessageRow.kindColumnBinary, Bytes.toBytes(row.kind))
  put.addColumn(SequencedMessageRow.messagesColumnFamilyBinary, SequencedMessageRow.binaryColumnBinary, row.binary)
  (new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put)
}.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(jobConfig.getConfiguration)
```

But because the time field is not unique, so I lost many duplicated rows. So how do people save this kind of data frame into HBase?

Comment: If you have versioning enabled in Hbase, then I would guess your duplicates wren't lost -- they were saved as multiple versions of the same rowKey/columnFamily/columnValue. Depending on how many duplicates you had per redundant rowKey, you may be able to retrieve them, at least as many as maxVersions in HBase. Of course this isn't an ideal approach -- you should have your rowKeys unique per row or devise a s strategy of appending a row key with a sequence, which will probably involve first a Get and then a Put.

Comment: @VS_FF thanks, and good to know those duplicated stuff goes into the versioning. For my case, I think I have to save the rows with same key into multiple columns.